How can I translate dynamic nested routes in nextjs 14?
I'm already using next-intl, react-i18next, next-i18n-router packages and I already setup static pages translation and stored it in my json file. But how can I setup it for dynamic data (blog) as it is coming from API.
If there is any way to implement google translate or any other free source to translate these dynamic pages, please let me know.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

In simple words, I wanna translate the dynamic pages for nextjs 14. The data in dynamic pages are coming from API
